# Transaction rollback on Spring JDBC tests

Tags: spring, testing, jdbc, transactions, rollback

I'm trying to get JDBC transaction rollback when using Spring-test without success. When I run the following the SQL update is always committed.

```
package my.dao.impl;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:ApplicationContext-test-DAOs.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class ConfirmationMatchingDAOImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Test
    public void shouldInsertSomething() throws Exception {
        final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("insert into TEST_INSERT values (1, 'hello')");
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://makeitfunky:1490;databaseName=fonzie"/>
    <property name="username" value="ralph"/>
    <property name="password" value="p0n1es_R_kew1"/>
</bean>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Additionally, am I using too many annotations? Can I make it a bit cleaner?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you do not explicitly configure test execution listeners using the `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation, Spring configures by default `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener`, `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener`, and `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`.  `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` provides transactional test execution with default rollback semantics.  By explicitly declaring `@TestExecutionListeners` on your test class and omitting `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` from the listeners list, you are disabling transactional support.

You must also add the `@Transactional` annotation at the class or method level.

You must also use [DataSourceUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html) to get a transactional Connection managed by DataSourceTransactionManager.

Comment: I removed @TestExecutionListeners and added @Transactional. I then had to add a transactionManager bean to the app-context (DataSourceTransactionManager). Txn was not rolled back so I added @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true). Txn was still not rolled back so I added @Rollback to the test method. Only then did I see Spring log that it was rolling back the txn, but the update still gets persisted to the DB. Something to do with SQL Server and its driver perhaps?

Comment: Added DataSourceUtils to my answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get notified of your last comment. In the meantime I have changed my context to wrap the datasource in a TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy. That worked. So there you go, two ways to do the same thing. Now to see which of these 7 annotations I can get rid of and still have the thing work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the non-xml method this works nicely since about version 3.1

```
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestDbConfig.class, SomeService.class})
public class SomeTest {

@Inject
private SomeService someService;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Test
public void someTest() {}
```

The test config then takes this form. Notice @EnableTransactionManagement and the fact you can declare a global test defaultRollback. This becomes particularly useful on a large projects.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:app.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class TestDbConfig {

//read the parameters from properties
@Value("${hibernate.dialect:unset}")
private String hibernateDialect;

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    //for example
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
    //set the datasource
    //set the JpaVendorAdapter
    //set the packagesToScan
    return some sort of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
DataSource dataSource() {
    return dataSource from jndi or a DriverManagerDataSource();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

add this annotation, and no roll back will be in test cases:

```
 @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)
```

My annotation looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/../applicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
public class DBCreatorTest {
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because you do not have an `@Transactional` for the test method?

Comment: I added @Transactional and it had no effect. I also added @Rollback and it still had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

When using the **@Transactional** annotation in Spring, you must add the following line to your Spring configuration file:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

The transaction-manager property holds a reference to the transaction manager bean defined in the Spring configuration file. This code tells Spring to use the @Transaction annotation when applying the transaction interceptor. Without it, the @Transactional annotation is ignored, resulting in no transaction being used in your code.

[Source on IBM website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1.html)

Comment: I can't remember what the problem actually was, but thanks for the extra info.

Answer (score 0):

additional informations :

for this line

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

The default value of the `transaction-manager` attribute is "transactionManager".
This attribute is required only if the bean id/name of the transactionManager is not 'transactionManager'.
So you just have to set :

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@Transactional` at class level.
Something like this :

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManager",defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
```

Here `txManager` is an instance or bean id of Transaction manager from `application context`.

```
<!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="txManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying out a lot of the above combinations, the following setup worked for me with full rollback after the test is successful.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:datasource-context-test.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class DataAccessTest 
{


    @Test
    public void testSaveRecords()
    { ... }
}
```